# Windows.Forms.DataGrid missing from Toolbox in VS2008

Tags: winforms, datagrid, .net-3.5

I am trying to add a DataGrid to my Windows Forms application and it seems that it is missing from the toolbox. Only DataGridView is available.

PS: I was able to manually add it to designer code. But nevertheless I am curious as to why it's not included in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the `DataGrid` was never in the Toolbox to begin with. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx), the `DataGrid`

> Displays ADO.NET data in a scrollable grid. The DataGridView control
>   replaces and adds functionality to the DataGrid control; however, the
>   DataGrid control is retained for both backward compatibility and
>   future use, if you choose.

Also, you should note that Visual Studio allows you to customize the items in the Toolbox. You can right click in the Toolbox, select "Choose Items" and then select `DataGrid` so that it will then appear in your toolbox.