# How to enable Horizontal Scroll bar in datagrid in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagrid with atleast 10 columns in it. But on loading the data the horizontal scroll bar does not show up. How to I get this fixed.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218819/horizontal-scrollbar-is-not-visible-on-datagridview)?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a  `DataGrid` or `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type

Comment: @TaW I am sorry but maybe you didn't read my question well enough I clearly mentioned in my question that this is regarding **Visual Studio 2008** and back in 2008 Visual Studio called **DataGridView as DataGrid** so I used the word

Comment: [No, I don't think so.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220907/windows-forms-datagrid-missing-from-toolbox-in-vs2008)

Comment: @TaW mate I am using 2008 right now. How could you be arguing about the name of the control. If you can help me with the Scroll bar issue please do. Thanks

Comment: You are right, sorry.. Of course I don't have VS08 but according to MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you should be able to do dg.HorizScrollBar.Visible = true.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

> columns has Frozen property set as True. which should be false for all columns.

Edited :

To  Frozen property using column using the designer
[image: Frozen true]

> Click the smart tag glyph on the upper-right corner of the DataGridView control, and then select Edit Columns.
>   Select a column from the Selected Columns list.
>   In the Column Properties grid, set the Frozen property to true.

```
    **or try this in code**
```

Set the DataGridViewColumn.Frozen property to true:

> dataGridView1.Columns("column").Frozen = True

Comment: In 2008 I can't seem to find the frozen property anywhere. I tried it using code as well but to my surprise in 2008 Studio datagrid didn't have the property called Columns as well so it's not helping

Answer (score -1):

There's a Property named `ScrollBars` where you can select wich of the scrollbars you'd like to see. Default is `Both`.

Comment: In 2008 Studio the datagrid does not have the property ScrollBars, I mostly use the latest version but for my current development I had to switch to 2008 and it's highly irritating